# Youtube playlist saver with Google API

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, youtube

I have a problem with Youtube videos being deleted from my big playlist and not knowing which videos got removed. So, I decided to write a Python script to save certain information(title etc.) about the videos in a playlist into a text-file. I particularly don't like the *setChannelNames()* func, but that's the best I could write it.

```
import os
import argparse
import codecs
import datetime
import sys
from apiclient.discovery import build

DEVELOPER_KEY = "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 50 #1-50 as per Google's rules.
MAX_PLAYLIST_SIZE = 5000

def getArgs():
    """
    Process command-line arguments.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Retrieve a list of youtube videos in a playlist.')
    parser.add_argument("id", type=str, metavar="id", help="Youtube ID of the playlist to scrap.")
    parser.add_argument('-dt', '--date', action='store_true', help="Include the date when the video was added to the playlist?")
    parser.add_argument('-ds', '--description', action='store_true', help="Include the description of videos?")
    parser.add_argument('-un', '--uploadername', action='store_true', help="Include the channel name of the uploader of video?")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    args = vars(args) #Turn into dict-like view.
    return args

def getExtraFields(args):
    """
    Returns a string of what information to filter in the Google API based on args optional parameters.
    """
    extraFields = ""

    if args["description"]:
        extraFields += ",description"

    if args["date"]:
        extraFields += ",publishedAt"

    if args["uploadername"]:
        extraFields += ",resourceId(videoId)"

    return extraFields

def getExtraInfo(args, item):
    """
    Returns a string of information to save with the video name based on args optional parameters.
    """
    extraInfo = ""

    if args["uploadername"]:
        extraInfo += " |Uploader: {}|".format(item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["uploader"])

    if args["date"]:
        extraInfo += " |Date Added: {}|".format(item["snippet"]["publishedAt"][:-5]) #-5 to remove 000Z

    if args["description"]:
        extraInfo += " |Description: {}|".format(item["snippet"]["description"])

    return extraInfo

def save(pages, fileName, args):
    """
    Saves selected playlistItems' information in a txt. 
    """
    f = codecs.open(fileName, "wb", "utf-8")

    i = 0
    for playlistItems in pages:
        for items in playlistItems["items"]:
            i = i + 1
            f.write("{}.".format(i) + str(items["snippet"]["title"]) + getExtraInfo(args, items) + u'\r\n')

    f.close()


def setChannelNames(pages):
    """
    Retrieves all the videos in pages and gets the uploader's name.
    Sets the uploader's name to the playlistItem's ["snippet"]["resourceId"]["uploader"].
    """
    #videoIds = [item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"] for playlistItem in pages for item in playlistItem["items"]]
    videoIds = []
    for playlistItems in pages:
        for items in playlistItems["items"]:
            videoIds.append(items["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"])

    for i in range(1, playlistItems["pageInfo"]["totalResults"]):
        videoIdsString = ""
        if i % RESULTS_PER_PAGE == 0 or i == playlistItems["pageInfo"]["totalResults"] - 1: #Every 50 or on the last iteration.
            for id in videoIds[:RESULTS_PER_PAGE]: #Generate the string of ids to put into the API request.
                videoIdsString += "{},".format(id)

            videoIdsString = videoIdsString[:-1] #Remove last ','
            videoIds = videoIds[RESULTS_PER_PAGE:]

            videos = youtube.videos().list(
                                        part="snippet",
                                        id=videoIdsString,
                                        fields="items(snippet(channelTitle))",
                                        maxResults=RESULTS_PER_PAGE
                                    ).execute()

            #Associate the channelTitles with their respective videos.
            j = 0
            for items in pages[int((i - 1) / 50)]["items"]:
                if j > len(videos["items"]) - 1:
                    print(j)
                    break

                items["snippet"]["resourceId"]["uploader"] = videos["items"][j]["snippet"]["channelTitle"]
                j+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if DEVELOPER_KEY == "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY":
        print("You must first enter your own Youtube Data API developer key. Check for more info: https://github.com/Majiick/YoutubePlaylistSnapshot/blob/master/README.md#usage")
        sys.exit()

    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    args = getArgs()
    extraFields = getExtraFields(args)


    pages = []
    nextPageToken = ""
    while True: #Get all the playListItems
        playlistItems = youtube.playlistItems().list(
            part="snippet", #What part to return.
            maxResults=RESULTS_PER_PAGE,
            playlistId=args["id"],
            pageToken=nextPageToken,
            fields="nextPageToken,pageInfo,items(snippet(title{0}))".format(extraFields) #Filters down returned information to only these fields.
        ).execute()

        if playlistItems["pageInfo"]["totalResults"] > MAX_PLAYLIST_SIZE:
            print("Playlist is too large. Edit MAX_PLAYLIST_SIZE to a higher value.")
            sys.exit()

        pages.append(playlistItems)

        if "nextPageToken" in playlistItems:
            nextPageToken = playlistItems["nextPageToken"]
        else:
            break

    if args["uploadername"]:
        setChannelNames(pages)


    playlistName = youtube.playlists().list(part="snippet", id=args["id"], fields="items(snippet(title))").execute()["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
    save(pages, "{} {}.txt".format(playlistName, datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')), args)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll give it a try but please bear with my answer as I don't have an API key to test this.

I'll start as I always do with some style guides which you can read about on the official page: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

#### 1.Comments

When writing inline comments, you should have two <kbd>space</kbd>s after the last character, and one <kbd>space</kbd> after `#` (e.g. `test_comment_string = 'some text'  # this is a test string comment`

#### 2.Spacing and formatting

Between methods you should have two spaces, not just one:

```
def getArgs():
    ...


def getExtraFields(args)
    ...
```

Try to limit all lines to max. 120 characters. The official documentation says the [maximum length](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) shouldn't be greater than 79. But I just like the [Intelij (Pycharm)](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) proposed style better (I guess here is a mater of preference but anyhow.. it helps readability)

Instead of `i = i + 1` you can use an augmented assignment: `i += 1`. I saw you used some of these assignments. Try to be consistent when writing code!

#### 3.Naming conventions

It's also specified in PEP8 the following (about variables / methods naming):

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.

That said, `extraFields` would become `extra_fields`

I've seen many people using also `camelCase` naming conventions for variables so as long as you're being consistent with your code it's ok.

The same rule applies for your methods:

`getArgs()` -> `get_args()`

#### 4.Imports

Don't import modules if you're not using them. It's confusing. For example, the `os` module is not used anywhere, so why would you `import` it ?

Doing all the above modifications, we now have the following:

```
import argparse
import codecs
import datetime
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build

DEVELOPER_KEY = "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 50  # 1-50 as per Google's rules.
MAX_PLAYLIST_SIZE = 5000


def get_args():
    """
    Process command-line arguments.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Retrieve a list of youtube videos in a playlist.')
    parser.add_argument("id", type=str, metavar="id", help="Youtube ID of the playlist to scrap.")
    parser.add_argument('-dt', '--date', action='store_true',
                        help="Include the date when the video was added to the playlist?")
    parser.add_argument('-ds', '--description', action='store_true', help="Include the description of videos?")
    parser.add_argument('-un', '--uploadername', action='store_true',
                        help="Include the channel name of the uploader of video?")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    args = vars(args)  # Turn into dict-like view.
    return args


def get_extra_fields(args):
    """
    Returns a string of what information to filter in the Google API based on args optional parameters.
    """
    extra_fields = ""

    if args["description"]:
        extra_fields += ",description"

    if args["date"]:
        extra_fields += ",publishedAt"

    if args["uploadername"]:
        extra_fields += ",resourceId(videoId)"

    return extra_fields


def get_extra_info(args, item):
    """
    Returns a string of information to save with the video name based on args optional parameters.
    """
    extra_info = ""

    if args["uploadername"]:
        extra_info += " |Uploader: {}|".format(item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["uploader"])

    if args["date"]:
        extra_info += " |Date Added: {}|".format(item["snippet"]["publishedAt"][:-5])  # -5 to remove 000Z

    if args["description"]:
        extra_info += " |Description: {}|".format(item["snippet"]["description"])

    return extra_info


def save(pages, file_name, args):
    """
    Saves selected playlistItems' information in a txt.
    """
    f = codecs.open(file_name, "wb", "utf-8")

    i = 0
    for playlist_items in pages:
        for items in playlist_items["items"]:
            i += 1
            f.write("{}.".format(i) + str(items["snippet"]["title"]) + get_extra_info(args, items) + u'\r\n')

    f.close()


def set_channel_names(pages):
    """
    Retrieves all the videos in pages and gets the uploader's name.
    Sets the uploader's name to the playlistItem's ["snippet"]["resourceId"]["uploader"].
    """
    # videoIds = [item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"] for playlistItem in pages for item in playlistItem["items"]]
    video_ids = []
    for playlist_items in pages:
        for items in playlist_items["items"]:
            video_ids.append(items["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"])

    for i in range(1, playlist_items["pageInfo"]["totalResults"]):
        video_ids_string = ""
        if i % RESULTS_PER_PAGE == 0 or i == playlist_items["pageInfo"]["totalResults"] - 1:
            for id in video_ids[:RESULTS_PER_PAGE]:  # Generate the string of ids to put into the API request.
                video_ids_string += "{},".format(id)

            video_ids_string = video_ids_string[:-1]  # Remove last ','
            video_ids = video_ids[RESULTS_PER_PAGE:]

            videos = youtube.videos().list(
                part="snippet",
                id=video_ids_string,
                fields="items(snippet(channelTitle))",
                maxResults=RESULTS_PER_PAGE
            ).execute()

            # Associate the channelTitles with their respective videos.
            j = 0
            for items in pages[int((i - 1) / 50)]["items"]:
                if j > len(videos["items"]) - 1:
                    print(j)
                    break

                items["snippet"]["resourceId"]["uploader"] = videos["items"][j]["snippet"]["channelTitle"]
                j += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if DEVELOPER_KEY == "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY":
        print("You must first enter your own Youtube Data API developer key.")
        sys.exit()

    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    args = get_args()
    extraFields = get_extra_fields(args)

    pages = []
    nextPageToken = ""
    while True:  # Get all the playListItems
        playlistItems = youtube.playlistItems().list(
            part="snippet",  # What part to return.
            maxResults=RESULTS_PER_PAGE,
            playlistId=args["id"],
            pageToken=nextPageToken,
            fields="nextPageToken,pageInfo,items(snippet(title{0}))".format(extraFields)
            # Filters down returned information to only these fields.
        ).execute()

        if playlistItems["pageInfo"]["totalResults"] > MAX_PLAYLIST_SIZE:
            print("Playlist is too large. Edit MAX_PLAYLIST_SIZE to a higher value.")
            sys.exit()

        pages.append(playlistItems)

        if "nextPageToken" in playlistItems:
            nextPageToken = playlistItems["nextPageToken"]
        else:
            break

    if args["uploadername"]:
        set_channel_names(pages)

    playlistName = \
    youtube.playlists().list(part="snippet", id=args["id"], fields="items(snippet(title))").execute()["items"][0][
        "snippet"]["title"]
    save(pages, "{} {}.txt".format(playlistName, datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')), args)
```

#### 5.A lil' bit more:

Here:

```
f.write("{}.".format(i) + str(items["snippet"]["title"]) + get_extra_info(args, items) + u'\r\n')
```

Using `str()` and then adding a unicode literal to it does not make a lot of sense. You may just want to use `u'...'.format()` instead.

This:

```
if "nextPageToken" in playlistItems:
   nextPageToken = playlistItems["nextPageToken"]
else:
   break
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
if not "nextPageToken" in playlistItems:
   break
nextPageToken = playlistItems["nextPageToken"]
```

That's what I've got so far. I really like how your code is structured. Your logic is well-defined and regarding `setChannelNames()` it looks pretty straight-forward to me.

As a general feedback, well-done!

*P.S: I might create and API Key to test your code later on when I'll have some more time. Then, I'll try to modify/improve a bit of the logic.*

Comment: Have mine, if you want - AIzaSyAny7lBhCSkwgUvCgyWkGKun30UPDse4To